# Write a SQL Server query to modify XML tag not value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

In my table column I have a value like:

```
    <Config>        
        <Aidgets>
            <widget condition="true" typesenums="1,2" templatetypes="a,b">
                <![CDATA[All]]>
            </widget>
            <widget condition="true" typesenums="1" templatetypes="a" >
                <![CDATA[pdfprints]]>
            </widget>
         <Aidgets>
    </Config>
```

Here I have to replace the value of

```
<widget condition="true" typesenums="1,2" templatetypes="a,b">
```

with

```
<widget condition="true" typesenums="1,2,3" templatetypes="a,b,c">
```

I have tried this but not working

```
UPDATE column
SET table = REPLACE(CAST(table AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), "firstvalue", "newvalue")
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: SQL Server has an XML type and XML functions. You can't modify XML with string replacements. You have to identify the correct element first, then modify its attrributes. Check the [replace value of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver15) page in the docs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to change the whole node node , value will be inside opening and closing tag,

Comment: How do you know which `widget` node to change?

Comment: @Charlieface first widget need to be changed , which have value <![CDATA[All]]>

Comment: You can use X.modify or do the casing in variable. For reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311535/replace-value-in-xml-using-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use two XQuery `.modify` updates to do this

```sql
UPDATE [column]
SET [table].modify('replace value of
    (Config/Aidgets/widget[text() = "All"]/@typesenums)[1]
    with "1,2,3"
    ');

UPDATE [column]
SET [table].modify('replace value of
    (Config/Aidgets/widget[text() = "All"]/@templatetypes)[1]
    with "a,b,c"
    ');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3f2f30243c4680ec89f424502febe5e8)

Alternatively, you can rebuild the whole XML instead.

```sql
UPDATE [column]
SET [table] = [table].query(
    '<Config>
    <Aidgets>
      {
        for $w in /Config/Aidgets/widget
        return
          if($w/text() = "All") then $w else
          <widget condition="true" typesenums="1,2,3" templatetypes="a,b,c">
            {$w/text()}
          </widget>
      }
    </Aidgets>
    </Config>'
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c8d197fcd6608c310cd07cc73e0fc2f)

Comment: I have ntext column dataType

Comment: Is there any reason you are not storing XML in an `xml` column? `ntext` is in any case deprecated, at the very least use `nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT, X XML);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 
N'<Config>        
   <Aidgets>
     <widget condition="true" typesenums="1,2" templatetypes="a,b">
        <![CDATA[All]]>
     </widget>
     <widget condition="true" typesenums="1" templatetypes="a" >
        <![CDATA[pdfprints]]>
     </widget>
   </Aidgets>
</Config>');

UPDATE T
   SET X.modify('replace value of (/Config/Aidgets/widget/@typesenums)[1] with "1, 2, 3"');
UPDATE T
   SET X.modify('replace value of (/Config/Aidgets/widget/@templatetypes)[1] with "a, b, c"');

SELECT * FROM T;
```

Comment: I have nText  column dataType

Comment: So convert it in XML !