# Find all xml elements by attribute and change their value using t-sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2019

How can I update multiple XML elements within a single document?

For example, if I have the XML below and I want to change any elements with an attribute `Store_ID="13"` to instead have `Store_ID="99"`.

```
declare @x xml 
select @x = N'
    <Games>
      <Game>
        <Place City="LAS" State="NV" />
        <Place City="ATL" State="GA" />
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="162" Description="Doom" />
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="575" Description="Pac-man" />
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Demons v3" />
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="123" Description="Whatever" />
      </Game>
    </Games>
'
select @x
```

I can find all the elements with SQL like this:

```
select t.c.query('.') 
from @x.nodes('.//*[@Store_ID="13"]') as t(c)
```

To update only the first element I could do an update like this (or change '1' to '2' to update the 2nd element, etc):

```
SET @x.modify('  
  replace value of (.//*[@Store_ID="13"]/@Store_ID)[1]  
  with "99"  
');  
SELECT @x;
```

The [docs for `replace value of`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) say I can only update one node at a time:

> It must identify only a single node ... When multiple nodes are selected, an error is raised.

So how do I update multiple elements? I can imagine querying first to find how many elements there are, then looping through and calling `@x.modify()` once for each element, passing an index parameter... but a) that feels wrong and b) when I try it I get an error

```
-- Find how many elements there are with the attribute to update
declare @numberOfElements int 
select @numberOfElements = count(*) 
from ( 
    select element = t.c.query('.') 
    from @x.nodes('.//*[@Store_ID="13"]') as t(c)
) x 

declare @i int = 1
declare @query nvarchar(max) 

-- loop through and update each one 
while @i <= @numberOfElements begin 

    SET @x.modify('  
      replace value of (.//*[@Store_ID="13"]/@Store_ID)[sql:variable("@i")]  
      with "99"  
    ');  
    set @i = @i + 1 ;  
end 

SELECT @x;
```

Running the sql above gives me the error:

```
Msg 2337, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
XQuery [modify()]: The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'attribute(Store_ID,xdt:untypedAtomic) *'
```

Furthermore, if I'm wanting to run this against many rows of a table with XML data stored in a column, it becomes very procedural.

Otherwise I could cast to `nvarchar(max)` and do string manipulation on it and then cast back to `xml`. Again, this feels icky, but also means I don't get the power of xml expressions to find the elements to update.

Answer (score 1):

If the XML structure is defined and well-known ahead of time then you could avoid the `XML.modify()` limitations by just recreating the XML with the edits applied inline.

**Example 1: reconstruct the XML with .nodes(), .values() and FOR XML**

```sql
update dbo.Example
set x = (
    select
        (
            select Place.value(N'@City', N'nvarchar(max)') as [@City],
                Place.value(N'@State', N'nvarchar(max)') as [@State]
            from Game.nodes('Place') as n(Place)
            for xml path(N'Place'), type
        ),
        (
            select
                case when (StoreID = 13) then 99 else StoreID end as [@Store_ID],
                PriceID as [@Price_ID],
                [Description] as [@Description]
            from Game.nodes('Store') as n(Store)
            cross apply (
                select  Store.value(N'@Store_ID', N'int'),
                    Store.value(N'@Price_ID', N'int'),
                    Store.value(N'@Description', N'nvarchar(max)')
            ) attributes(StoreID, PriceID, [Description])
            for xml path('Store'), type
        )
    from x.nodes(N'/Games/Game') Games(Game)
    for xml path(N'Game'), root(N'Games')
);
```

**Example 2: reconstruct the XML with XQuery**

```sql
update dbo.Example
set x = (
    select  x.query('
<Games>
    <Game>
        {
            for $place in /Games/Game/Place
                return $place
        }
        {
            for $store in /Games/Game/Store
                let $PriceID := $store/@Price_ID
                let $StoreID_Input := xs:integer($store/@Store_ID) 
                let $StoreID := if ($StoreID_Input != 13) then $StoreID_Input else 99
                let $Description := $store/@Description
                return <Store Store_ID="{$StoreID}" Price_ID="{$PriceID}" Description="{$Description}"/>
        }
    </Game>
</Games>')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of this! Unfortunately my XML is complex and not fully defined, and the parts I want to update are tiny relative to the whole. So this would be a risky way to do it as I'll probably lose some of the original if I try to reconstruct it. Still a great approach for some cases of this problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another relatively generic method by using XQuery.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @x XML =
N'<Games>
    <Game>
        <Place City="LAS" State="NV"/>
        <Place City="ATL" State="GA"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="162" Description="Doom"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="575" Description="Pac-man"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Demons v3"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="123" Description="Whatever"/>
    </Game>
</Games>';

DECLARE @oldId int = 13
    , @newId int = 99;

SET @x = @x.query('<Games><Game>
    {
        for $i in /Games/Game/*
        return if ($i[(local-name()="Store") and @Store_ID=sql:variable("@oldId")]) then
            element Store { attribute Store_ID {sql:variable("@newId")}, $i/@*[not(local-name()="Store_ID")]}
        else $i
    }
</Game></Games>');

-- test
SELECT @x;
```

**Output**

```
<Games>
  <Game>
    <Place City="LAS" State="NV" />
    <Place City="ATL" State="GA" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="162" Description="Doom" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="575" Description="Pac-man" />
    <Store Store_ID="99" Price_ID="167" Description="Demons v3" />
    <Store Store_ID="99" Price_ID="123" Description="Whatever" />
  </Game>
</Games>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320582/8479) it's not possible to update multiple times in a single statement, so to use xml you need to loop and call `modify()` repeatedly until all values are updated.

My initial attempt to loop was misfounded: simply do the `modify()` on the first matching element until there's no more:

```
while @x.exist('.//*[@Store_ID="13"]')=1
begin 

    SET @x.modify('  
      replace value of (.//*[@Store_ID="13"]/@Store_ID)[1]
      with "99"  
    ');  
end
```

In my trivial examples I've used hardcoded values `"13"` and `"99"` but for real code you can use `sql:variable("@variableName")` ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable?view=sql-server-ver16)) and `sql:column("tableNameOrAlias.colName")` ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-column?view=sql-server-ver16)), e.g.

```
declare @oldId int = 13
    ,   @newId int = 99 

while @x.exist('.//*[@Store_ID=sql:variable("@oldId")]')=1
begin 

    SET @x.modify('  
      replace value of (.//*[@Store_ID=sql:variable("@oldId")]/@Store_ID)[1]
      with sql:variable("@newId")  
    ');  
end
```